# Random number generation in OCaml

Tags: random, ocaml

When using strict functional languages you are bound to a way of writing programs. I come with the problem of generating large quantity of pseudo random numbers with OCaml and I'm not sure I'm using the best way to generate this numbers on such language.

What I did was create a module with a function (*gen*) that takes an integer as the *size* and an empty list and returns a list of pseudo random numbers of size *size*. The problem is when the size is to large, it asserts a ***StackOverflow*** which is what is expected.

Should I use tail recursion? Should I use a better method that I'm not aware of?

```
module RNG =
struct
  (* Append a number n in the end of the list l *)
  let rec append l n =
    match l with
    | [] -> [n]
    | h :: t -> h :: (append t n)

  (* Generate a list l with size random numbers *)
  let rec gen size l =
    if size = 0 then
      l
    else
      let n = Random.int 1000000 in
      let list = append l n in
      gen (size - 1) list
end
```

Testing the code to generate a billion pseudo random numbers returns:

```
# let l = RNG.gen 1000000000 [];;
Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).
```

Comment: Does the first method could be improved to now walk over the entire list to append a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the append function is not tail recursive. Each recursion uses up a bit of stack space to store it's state and as the list gets longer the append function takes more and more stack space. As some point the stack simply isn't big enough and the code fails.

As you suggested in the question the way to avoid that is using tail recursion. When working with lists that usually means constructing the lists in reverse order. The append function then becomes simply `::`.

If the order of the resulting list is important the list needs to be reversed at the end. So it is not uncommon to see code returning `List.rev acc`. This takes O(n) time but constant space and is tail recursive. So the stack is no limit there.

So your code would become:

```
let rec gen size l =
  if size = 0 then
    List.rev l
  else
    let n = Random.int 1000000 in
    let list = n :: l in
    gen (size - 1) list
```

A few more things to optimize:

When building a result bit by bit through recursion the result is usually names `acc`, short for accumulator, and passed first:

```
let rec gen acc size =
  if size = 0 then
    List.rev acc
  else
    let n = Random.int 1000000 in
    let list = n :: acc in
    gen list (size - 1)
```

This then allows the use of function and pattern matching instead of the size argument and if construct:

```
let rec gen acc = function
| 0 -> List.rev acc
| size ->
    let n = Random.int 1000000 in
    let list = n :: acc in
    gen list (size - 1)
```

A list of random numbers is usually just as good reversed. Unless you want lists of different sizes but using the same seed to begin with the same sequence of numbers you can skip the List.rev. And `n :: acc` is such a simple costruct one usually doesn't bind that to a variable.

```
let rec gen acc = function
| 0 -> acc
| size ->
    let n = Random.int 1000000 in
    gen (n :: acc) (size - 1)
```

And last you can take advantage of optional arguments. While that makes the code a bit more complex to read it greatly simplifies it's use:

```
let rec gen ?(acc=[]) = function
  | 0 -> acc
  | size ->
      let n = Random.int 1000000 in
      gen ~acc:(n :: acc) (size - 1)

# gen 5;;
- : int list = [180439; 831641; 180182; 326685; 809344]
```

You no longer need to specify the empty list to generate a list of random number.

Note: An alternative way is to use a wrapper function:

```
let gen size =
  let rec loop acc = function
    | 0 -> acc
    | size ->
        let n = Random.int 1000000 in
        loop (n :: acc) (size - 1)
  in loop [] size
```

Comment: Great answer! I've done some things you mentioned before you answered but you showed me so much more. +1

Answer (score 2):

It would be a big improvement to generate your list in reverse order, then reverse it once at the end. Adding successive values to the end of a list is very slow. Adding to the front of a list can be done in constant time.

Even better, just generate the list in reverse order and return it that way. Do you care that the list is in the same order that the values were generated?

Comment: I don't care in which order the list is generated and I will do just as you said.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to compute the full list explicitly? Another option might be to generate the element lazily (and deterministically) using the new sequence module:

```
   let rec random_seq state () =
     let state' = Random.State.copy state in
     Seq.Cons(Random.State.int state' 10, random_seq state')
```

Then the random sequence `random_seq state` is fully determined by the initial state `state`: it can be  both reused without troubles and only generate new elements as needed.

Comment: I don't have a requisite to generate the entire list explicitly, I was just trying to do it that way. Thanks for the information and I will try it, I didn't know that in OCaml I could use lazy constructions.

Comment: I'm sorry but there's a better answer for this question and therefore I changed it to benefit of the entire SO community.

Comment: Note that it depends a lot on your use case. When working with sequence of random variables, it is very common to be ultimately interested in some reduced observable, like the mean, a handful of moments or a histogram. In this case, it may be better to use sequence (or lazy lists) to compute the reduced data on the fly rather than computing the full sequence first in memory and then apply the reducer to the full data set.

Answer (score 1):

The standard `List` module has an `init` function you can use to write all this in one line:

```
let upperbound = 10

let rec gen size =
  List.init size (fun _ -> Random.int upperbound)
```

Comment: I hit some performance issues with my memory when doing this way. It consumes a lot of memory (lots of allocations) and I had to stop it when it reached ~15GiB. Is there a way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml#L62-L82). If you don't need the list to be in a specific order you can use the tail recursive implementation without the list reversal, which should cut the memory requirement in half. 15GB seems a tad excessive, but it's on the right order of magnitude if you're allocating 1 billion cons cells. Perhaps a list isn't the right data structure for your use case. A sequence, as @octachron suggests, seems a better fit.